# Animation when displaying AdMob interstitial ads (Swift, GADInterstitial)

Tags: swift, animation, admob

I plan to add AdMob interstitial ads to my app. Everything works correctly, but I would like to change the animation of the appearance of advertising. By default, the ad unit is displayed up from down. I would like to either change the animation to dissolve or turn it off completely. Is there such an opportunity?

**What I have:**

1. `GADInterstitial` object that inherits from `NSObject`

   > @interface GADInterstitial: NSObject
2. The `present` method:

   > (void) presentFromRootViewController: (nonnull UIViewController *)
   >   rootViewController;

**My code:**

```
// Ad loading
let interstitial= GADInterstitial(adUnitID: MY_AD_UNIT_ID)
interstitial.load(GADRequest())

// Ad displaying
if interstitial.isReady {
    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: MY_VIEW_CONTROLLER)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for an answer about 6 months ago and was told by an SDK engineer there is no method for animating an interstitial using the GAD framework. I guess it is within some reasonable possibility that you could modify the framework to accommodate a different style animation, but it would be ill-advised. You can, however, animate banner ads from AdMob.